# Javascript assining a function to other function on if

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading a Nodejs book and I came accross to this syntax below

```
function createClient (ns, opts) {
  return createClient[ns] || (createClient[ns] = nos(net.connect(opts)))
}
```

Didn't quite understand the `createClient[ns] = nos(net.connect(opts))` part, What it means? Why should I use it?

Is this syntax documented anywhere?

Comment: This is an assignment expression. It performs an assignment and evaluates to the assigned value for further use in an expression. So it represents an evaluation with side effects, and therefore not everyone is as happy with this pattern. See [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment#Return_value_and_chaining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taking advantage of the ability to chain the assignment operator to assign values to multiple variables at once. Stated another way, the return value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned.

The simplest demonstration is to the log the output of an assignment operation:

```js
console.log(test = 'foo');
```

This behavior is mentioned in [the MDN docs for the assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment):

> Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a
> single value to multiple variables

In your code snippet, the intention seems to be "return the value of `createClient[ns]` unless it's false (e.g. unassigned), otherwise assign the value of `nos(net.connect(opts))` to `createClient[ns]` and return that value."

This is a simple form of caching and implies that `nos()` is an expensive operation that shouldn't be repeated unless necessary.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
let values = {};

function assignIfNotSet(arg) {
  return values['example'] || (values['example'] = arg);
}

console.log('before:');
console.log(values);

let result = assignIfNotSet('foo');

console.log('after:');
console.log(values);

console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Comment: I think what confused me it's the absense of the variable (createClient) declaration, and the function and the variable have the same name. In your case you declared `let values = {}`

Comment: Ah, `createClient` is a function object. The fact that it's an object is important, as that means properties can be defined on it. In your code snippet, instead of creating an extra object outside of the function scope, the cached value is defined as a property of the function object itself. Since the function object exists in the scope where the function is defined, it's properties persist between invocations (i.e. it's scope is the same as `values` in my example).